# Why do my grid columns wrap to a second line?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 buttons using Bootstrap 4.  I have defined them each to be 4 columns of the grid, so I figured they would all stay on 1 row.  However the 3rd button is dropping down to the next line and I can't figure out why.

I've made a codepen here: https://codepen.io/xanabobana/pen/pobRxpx

HTML:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 button button-header button-tools-collections"><a href="<?php echo site_url('products/tools/'); ?>"><h3>Tools</h3>  <span class="badge"><span class="fa fa-wrench fa-2x"></span></span></a></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 button button-header button-tools-collections"><a href="<?php echo site_url('products/collections/'); ?>"><h3>Collections</h3>  <span class="badge"><span class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></span></span></a></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 button button-header button-tools-collections"><a href="<?php echo site_url('cooperative/regional_projects/'); ?>"><h3>Regional Projects</h3>  <span class="badge"><span class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></span></span></a></div>
     
        </div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.button-header {
    border: 3px solid #b8d87a;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .8em;
    margin: 2em 1em 2em 0;
}

.button-header a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    display: block;
}

.button-header a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.button-header .arrow {
    font-family: arial;
}

.button-tools-collections a {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is that the right Codepen link? It doesn't demonstrate the problem (and there's some JavaScript in there, which there probably shouldn't be). It doesn't match the code that's here.

Answer (score 0):

You've put styles on the columns that make them wider. That's not a good practice. Use layout elements for layout and put elements inside those for styling.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
   <div class="button button-header button-tools-collections">
       <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/tools/'); ?>">
          <h3>Tools</h3> 
          <span class="badge"><span class="fa fa-wrench fa-2x"></span></span>
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```